# Philippine national moving to Austria to live with boyfriend - Visa options

Tags: schengen, austria, working-visas

I'm a Philippine national working in Dubai. My boyfriend (who is an EU national) is working in Austria full-time and we want to live together so the plan is for me to move to Austria.

I still have some days left on my Schengen multiple-entry visa, which I intend to use soon to visit him. Then I'll be left with very few days on my visa.

My plan is to work or get another degree (study) BSc./MSc. in Austria. I know it is nearly impossible to find a job there while not being there so my plan is to look for a job while there. Also, my professional skills in Austria would require me to speak German.

I've thought of the following possibilities:

1. Get a student visa to study in Austria and have a part-time job while studying. Maybe drop out of university if I managed to get a full-time job, but that would require to change my visa status, which I believe to not be difficult while being already in Austria with a valid visa.
2. Get a vis to study German. This would be a short-term solution but it would allow me to look for a job while attending the German language school (German would definitely help me getting a job) and let me pursue my career with my current professional skills or change career paths.
3. Get a 6-month or 90-day tourist visa and after landing there request a living permit and then search for a job.
4. How difficult is it to get a living permit from a tourist visa in Austria? Even when my boyfriend will be providing me with housing and support.
5. Is it possible to get a working visa while not actually having a job in Austria? I believe it is not possible at all.
6. Any other possible solution that I've not mentioned?

While I mentioned a visa to study German and for a university degree, and also looking for a job, I do really intend on doing the studies (university or German language) in Austria and not use the visa as an excuse to move to Vienna and not attend anything.

Also, my boyfriend can support me in any way - housing will be provided by him. Is there anything that my boyfriend can do to help me with the visa process?

What are my best options to get a visa to move to Austria?

Comment: While your boyfriend can help very little, your fiancé can do more, and your husband would easily solve it.

Comment: Is your boyfriend Austrian or does he have a different EU nationality?  @ugoren freedom of movement extends to a "partner" in a "durable relationship, duly attested," although the interpretation of that phrase is leftto individual EU member states.

Comment: @phoog He is not Austrian but from a different EU nationality

Comment: Is your relationship with your boyfriend such that you could present yourselves as "life partners"?  (The phrase in the English version of the directive is "the partner with whom the Union citizen has a durable relationship, duly attested"; in German, it's "des Lebenspartners, mit dem der Unionsbürger eine ordnungsgemäß bescheinigte dauerhafte Beziehung eingegangen ist"; and in Austrian law it's "...wenn sie Lebenspartner sind, der das Bestehen einer dauerhaften Beziehung nachweist.")

Comment: @phoog unfortunately, I've no physical proof to show this is a durable relationship. I also think a durable relationship can be a subjective thing up to the person to interpret how they feel like too... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pat If you move to austria, your first stop must be language school, you will not be able to get any kind of job without speaking the language. If you want to study, this is even more important, most lectures are in german. Note, that you will need a very high degree of proficiency to follow a lecture.